# java loop, if else

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, if-statement

I know this is something very simple, however, I've only been programming for a couple months so my brain just fog's out sometimes, and I need help with a while loop with nested else if statements. The problem my loop is continuous because the user is never given the chance to enter in their choice (which -1 stops the loop). How can I change the loop so that it operates by asking user to enter a choice (1-4, or -1 to quit)

Please Any help is appreciated. I know it's something simple, I've searched thorugh previous forum discussions but I can't seem to make it work.

```
//create new scanner object 
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    int end = 0;
    //find out what user wants to do with address book
    while (end != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do with your address book? ...");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Add new         [Enter 1]");
        System.out.println("Delete existing [Enter 2]");
        System.out.println("Edit existing   [Enter 3]");
        System.out.println("Search for      [Enter 4]");
        System.out.println("EXIT            [Enter -1]");
    }

    if (userInput.hasNext() && (userInput.nextInt() == 1)) 
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.addContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 2)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.deleteContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 3)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.editContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 4)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.findContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.nextInt() != 1 || userInput.nextInt() != 2 
                     || userInput.nextInt() != 3 || userInput.nextInt() != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
        end = -1;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your if/else's inside the while loop.

Comment: thanks, my brain is getting tired and everything has to be in tonight, just been seeing code non-stop for 4 days straight!

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the `end` variable inside the `while` loop, so that results in an infinite loop.  You will need to place your input processing logic inside the while loop so that `end` has a chance to change, so that the `while` loop can end.

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting the if statement inside the loop should work (note I haven't checked anything else on the code this is just a quick response):

```
//create new scanner object 
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    int end = 0;
    //find out what user wants to do with address book
    while (end != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do with your address book? ...");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Add new         [Enter 1]");
        System.out.println("Delete existing [Enter 2]");
        System.out.println("Edit existing   [Enter 3]");
        System.out.println("Search for      [Enter 4]");
        System.out.println("EXIT            [Enter -1]");
    if (userInput.hasNext() && (userInput.nextInt() == 1)) 
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.addContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 2)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.deleteContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 3)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.editContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.hasNext() && userInput.nextInt() == 4)
    {
        AddressBookProcessor.findContact();
    }
    else if (userInput.nextInt() != 1 || userInput.nextInt() != 2 
                     || userInput.nextInt() != 3 || userInput.nextInt() != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
        end = -1;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks also ;-)  I feel like a re-re now, whatever ,I'm tired..